# Getting Java3D to work in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-3d

I am trying to get J3D to work in Eclipse and have read forum after forum but can't seem to fix my problem. I am using ubuntu 11.10

I have done this:

0) unzipped j3d-1_5_2-linux-i586 in home/j3d directory then added i386 folder to usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdkjre/lib/i386

1) Window--> Preferences--> User Libraries --> New and added the three .jar files (j3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar, vecmath.core)

2) Added a native library location to point to usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdkjre/lib/i386 where the .so files are

Some sources say try adding the .jar files to your Classpath Variable which didn't fix the problem for me.

I keep getting

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libj3dcore-ogl.so: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libj3dcore-ogl.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1750)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1667)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline$1.run(NativePipeline.java:231)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.loadLibrary(NativePipeline.java:200)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.loadLibraries(NativePipeline.java:157)
    at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:987)
    at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.(VirtualUniverse.java:299)
    at Hello3d.(Hello3d.java:13)
    at Hello3d.main(Hello3d.java:27)

[image: These are my directories]

Comment: what is your eclipse version? I am using without a problem. You can import to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems. Most tutorials tell you to assign an new library, but i mixed the Java3D files with the `JDK` files and re installed eclipse. If this doesn't work use net Beans.

Comment: This is not a good practice to mixing libraries with JDK files. How do you imagine will client use your product?

Comment: What do you mean? i Had to mix my files so it would actually read the files correctly. i have yet to run into problems with it.

Comment: i didn't mean to sound snooty, i may be wrong i did do allot of fooling around in the java file